# What python env is pycharms console using?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pycharm

I'm trying to make a script that runs nosetest with extra commands via nose-testconfig depending on my needs.

It works when running the file from a terminal window, but when run from inside pycharm it seems to not find the nose-testconfig package. I'm using virtualenv and I've installed all packages from inside pycharm, the virtualenv is correct but it seems that when I do calls by using os.system it doesn't use my virtualenv.

Code:

```
import os

os.system("pip freeze")
os.system("nosetests -s --tc=folder:bar runtests.py")
```

Result:

```
argparse==1.2.1
distribute==0.6.24
nose==1.3.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
Usage: nosetests [options]

nosetests: error: no such option: --tc
```

Comment: Try running PyCharm from the terminal: `open -a /Applications/PyCharm.app/`, otherwise it [has no access to this environment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891).

Comment: @CrazyCoder `open: invalid option -- 'a'`.

Comment: If it's Linux, just run `bin/pycharm.sh` from the bash shell. My answer was for Mac as you didn't specify the OS in the question and this issue is most common on Macs.

Comment: @CrazyCoder: What about for windows?

Comment: @Felix Did you try Run->Edit config->+ Python: create custom runner for your tasks?

Answer (score 1):

The currently configured Python Interpreter. You can check the currently configured interpreter like so:

[image]
[image]